# discord.py - mention through ID doesn't show name

Tags: google-sheets, discord, discord.py, gspread

I'm using rewrite and gspread to update a 'top 16' leaderboard by storing the user ID and score. The formula to create/update the leaderboard places the ID of a user in a cell by referencing their position depending on their score. So each cell is structured like so:

```
 1st place: <"@230579325375837234">
```

I'm then pulling the entire column out to edit an existing embed:

```
lb = sheet13.col_values(9)
```

This all works fine - my issue is that the edited embed does not always convert the ID to a name. Some are converted to names and others are mentioned versions of the ID, opposed to mentioning the username. Leading to an embed that looks like:

```
 1st place: @adisplayname
 2st place: <@230579325375837234>
 3rd place: @anotherdisplayname
 4th place: <@573856332907428873>
 5th place: <@230579325375837234>
 6th place: @thirddisplayname
```

Is there a way to assure that user/display_names are mentioned, and not the IDs?

I'm thinking of pulling the individual cells that are used to update the embed rather than the entire column and defining them as individual variables to mention the user by display_name; rather than trying to mention the raw ID itself, although I'm not sure this solution is the cleanest?

Comment: Are the users whose mentions aren't resolving still in your guild?  Mentions will only work if the member is in the guild

Comment: Yeah, these are definitely members still in the guild

Comment: You could store the ids and then get the Member object when building your embed and use the `Member.mention` attribute.

Comment: Are you able to manually mention them if you send a message containing one of the failed mentions, such as `<@230579325375837234>`?

Comment: In your post you show one formatted as `<"@230579325375837234">`, which will be invalid, not sure if this has anything to do with your issue or not, but you might try just storing the user id and then manually building the mention syntax when you update your embed.

Comment: thanks for your first advice derw, i discovered the solution through this :) and the quotes within my ID's are indeed a mistake in the post - i'm using them in the sheet `="**1st**: <@!" & F2 & ">"`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to derw, I ran a whois command to check that the members were definitely in the server and the reply included an ! in front of the ID. This appears to have fixed my issue.

```
1st place: <@!23057932537583723>
```

All mentions are now working :)